# Jquery display preloader once all div elements have been Retrieved

Tags: jquery

I want to display a preloader in a div and once another div has retrieved all its content I want the preloader to disappear.

For Example:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="preloader">
     loading....
   </div>
   <div id="containeritems">
   image
```

The container should be displayed first and then the preloader and once all the elements have been loaded I want the preloader div to disappear.

I have tried load and show and hide, the show and hide work but div.load function is not supported I think for `divs` how else can I listen to the containeritems div so I can tell the elements have been loaded?

Comment: <script>

$function() {

$("#myelementid").load(function() {

alert("my element is fully loaded");

});

});
</script>

Comment: I amended this code to fit mine but couldn't get the load to work

Comment: post your response as an answer to receive credit (potentially!)

Comment: also tried amended the following code from Jquery  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $("p").text("The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.");
});
  </script>

Answer (score 0):

When I am retrieving data from the server or saving I use

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(PageLoaded);

function PageLoaded(sender, args) {
  $('#elem').hide();

}
```